# Click on link changes the url but not the content/data on page

Tags: vue-router, vue.js

**the story:**

I am on product page `#/product/7` and on the same page I have 4 more products that are similar to the one that is being viewed. All these products have links to their pages:

`router-link(:to="{ name: 'product', params: { id: product.id }}" v-text='product.title')`.

**the problem:**

When I click on any of the product links, the url changes but the content remains the same. So, if I am on `#/product/7` and click on `#/product/8` the url only will change. If I navigate from `/product/:id` page and click on a product it takes me to the right page with proper content.

[image]

As you can see on screenshot, current product id is 15, but the content is the one from the id 7, as shown in url at the bottom while I was hovering over the Sleek Silk Shirt product in cart.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to update the data of products variable when you change the route as vue optimises page reloads and does not reload in your case if you are on same route.

You can adapt the approach: `Fetching Before Navigation`  described in vue-router [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html):

> With this approach we fetch the data before actually navigating to the new route. We can perform the data fetching in the beforeRouteEnter guard in the incoming component, and only call next when the fetch is complete:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      product: {},
      error: null
    }
  },
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    getProduct(to.params.id, (err, product) => {
      if (err) {
        // display some global error message
        next(false)
      } else {
        next(vm => {
          vm.product = product
        })
      }
    })
  },
  // when route changes and this component is already rendered,
  // the logic will be slightly different.
  watch: {
    $route () {
      this.product = {}
      getProduct(this.$route.params.id, (err, product) => {
        if (err) {
          this.error = err.toString()
        } else {
          this.product = product
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you so  much. :)

Comment: This is very helpfull, I was running into a bug that was solved by adding the next() method on the beforeRouteEnter hook.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that, while the above is v. helpful, only the watch() part is required to fix the OP's issue. Loading data in beforeRouteEnter() is only one of a few possible valid design choices to load data for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt really internalise the above answer with 'getProduct', so to be put simply.

I am using a Store and I needed to watch the $route and when it changes I called my store to dispatch the api call.

```
watch: {
    $route () {
      this.$store.dispatch('fetchStudyStandards', 
      this.$route.params.standardID);
    }
}
```

So basically watch the route and if it changes, re do your api call.